# Python Pickle throwing EOFError

Tags: python, pickle

```
already_done = ['lol', 'lol2']
already_done = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

That little snippet of code throws an EOFError from pickle, no matter if save.p exists or not.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `save.p` a valid python pickle?  If not, it'll throw that exception.  How was it created?

Comment: @g.d.d.c  If I try and run that code when save.p exists, it's by creating an empty file and renaming it save.p

Comment: In which case, you completely misunderstand what you're attempting to accomplish.  You have to use `pickle.load` against a file that was previously created with `pickle.dump`.  If you haven't done that, then this error is telling you that the `pickle` module can't parse what it finds in the file you indicated according to the rules it uses to reload things that it saved using its rules.  You have a disconnect in your expectations.

Comment: @g.d.d.c  I see what you mean.  How I ended up bodging it is I made a little separate program which generates a valid .p file, and then loading it with the main program.  Not the best way, but I only have to do it once.  Now that the file exists, I can dump and load as I please.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish using pickle this way?

Comment: @Eevee I'm running a program via cronjob every few minutes, and the dictionary in the program needs to transfer between instances of the program.  So at the beginning of the program I load the dictionary saved a minute ago, and then at the end of the program I dump the dictionary with the changes I made to it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain why you expect your code snippet to work, but it's failing because you're not understanding how pickle works.  By way of example:

```
>>> s = (1,2,3)
>>> pickle.dump(s, open('save.p', 'wb'))
>>> s2 = pickle.load(open('save.p', 'b'))
>>> s2
(1, 2, 3)
```

You have to write something out using the pickle module before you can reload it.